# What does path designator .: stand for?

Tags: path, html

In my apache2 error log I'm seeing (include_path='.:/usr/share/php'). I've never seen that as part of a path designator before. I've researched path designators and found no answers. What does the .: stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. The `:` is a *separator* between paths; the parameter lists two locations, `.` and `/usr/share/php`.